# Alternative for Javascript this object

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a simple function which routes a HTTP query pattern, queries redis and sends a response. The following is the code

```
router.get('/getinfo/:teamname', function main(teamname) {

  rclient.hgetall(teamname,function(err,obj){
        console.log("the response from redis is ",obj)
        cache.put(eventname,obj);
        console.log("inserting to cache");  
        this.res.end(obj); // this object is root cause for all problems
    });
}
```

The router object afaik, sends the response using `this.res.end(obj)` . I guess since I am trying to do this inside my redis client , I am getting error. Is there any other way to send the value as a response ?  I thought of using emitter based model where the channel emits the response and listener gets it. but it feels like a round about way to solving this problem. Is there any simpler approach ?

Comment: Is `res` available in any of the enclosed functions?

Comment: remember that javascript is asnychronous. So, `this` in your callback could be not the `this` you except to be it. Maybe it´s referencing the `this` from inside the `rclient` object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error may be because, where you're trying to use `this`, it doesn't have the intended value -- an object with a `res` property that in turn has an `end()` method.

That would be because every `function` in JavaScript has its own `this` with its own value. And, when nesting `function`s, using `this` will return the value for the closest `function` (i.e. [shadowing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing)).

To resolve that, you can save the intended value to a local variable:

```
router.get('/getinfo/:teamname', function main(teamname) {
    var request = this;

    rclient.hgetall(teamname,function(err,obj){
        // ...
        request.res.end(obj);
    });
});
```

Or, [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) the anonymous callback so both `function`s are forced to have the same `this` value:

```
router.get('/getinfo/:teamname', function main(teamname) {
    rclient.hgetall(teamname, function(err,obj){
        // ...
        this.res.end(obj);
    }.bind(this));
});
```

Comment: The bind option is soo much cooler. It has saved my day..! Thanks a ton!